# Finding setup date of Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

Someone asked me: Should we not celebrate 10year anniversary for our AzureAD. Do you know the exact date?
Me: No problem, I'll find out. Give me a minute with powershell...
Two days later I am still trying to figure it out.

I have the creation date for our oldest account as a pretty decent answer, but the actual oldest account could be deleted. So, I would like to have the exact date/time for the AAD Instantiation. I guess its an "OCD thing".

**Summarize:

Do anyone know how to find the "whenCreated" for an Azure AD instance?**
Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Microsoft Graph [Get organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization
```

There is a property named `createdDateTime` which is what you want.

Have a quick test in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Sign in with your admin account and query the organization:

[image]

Comment: Perfect: After adjusting permissions (consent) I now have the datetime.

Comment: @RaymondA. Great! If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: Of course it should been marked as accepted answer. Thank you for reminding me, I simply forgot.