# How to determine the date of creation of an Azure tenant?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there a way to determine when an Azure directory was created?
After checking on ASC, or looking for a PowerShell cmdlet as well, I was unable to find information related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Please see Microsoft Graph [Get organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65766245/finding-setup-date-of-azure-active-directory/65768010#65768010).

Call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization` in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) (sign in with your AAD admin account and click on **Modify permissions** to consent `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission).

[image]

Find the `createdDateTime` property in the response.